# подскажите что не так, зацикливается

Tags: c++

```
/* Программа Lab9_1 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x,x0,xn,hx,y;

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    printf("Введите x0(hx)xn\n");

    scanf("%f",&x0);
    scanf("%f",&hx);
    scanf("%f",&xn);

    x = x0;
    do
    { 
        if(x>=5)
            printf("x = %f  Функция не определена\n", x);
        else
        {
            if (x < 1)
                y = x*x;
            else 
                if (x >= 1 && x <= 3)
                    y = sqrt(x+1);
                else
                    y = sin(x);
            printf("x = %f  y = %f\n", x, y);
            x = x + hx; 
        };


    } while (x <= xn + hx/3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какие значения вводили? Что выводит?

Comment: Прога правильная, делает то, что вы написали. Условия задачи Lab9 напишите, что она должна была делать.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел причину. Код сам по себе работает корректно, а когда вводите вещественные числа, возможно вместо точки вводите запятую, или наоборот (например, не 0.5, а 0,5).
Вводил вот такие данные:
- первый раз: 2 0.25 4
- второй:     0.5 0.1 2
Всё корректно работало.
Если у Вас зацикливается, то попробуйте ввести вот так:
- первый раз: 2 0,25 4
- второй:     0,5 0,1 2

Comment: ТС такого не говорил, что вводит через запятую.